# How to minimise a sum of two functions allowing one of the arguments to vary over both functions?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have two functions **f(x,y,z)** and **g(x,y,z)**. I want to minimise the sum
**h(x,y,z) = f(x,y,z) + g(x,y,z)**, allowing **x** to be variable over both functions **f** and **g**.

I can minimise both these functions separately or together using `scipy.optimise.minimise`, which basically calculates the values of f + g (or h) at a bunch of x, y and z values, and then returns me the values (x, y, z) for which f + g is minimum.
What happens here is that : both f and g are evaluated at same values of (x, y, z), but I want one of the arguments (say x) to vary over f and g.

This is a rough outline of what I am trying:

```
    def f(x,y,z):
        return scalar

    def g(x,y,z):
        return another_scalar

    def h(theta):
        x, y, z = theta
        return f(x,y,z) + g(x,y,z)

  
    def bestfit(guess, method='Nelder-Mead'):
        result = op.minimize(h,
                             guess,
                             method=method,
                             options={'maxfev': 5000,
                                      'disp': False})

        if not result.success:
            print('Optimisation did not converge.')

        return result

    g = [x0, y0, z0]
    bf = bestfit(g, method='Nelder-Mead')
    print(bf)
```

I am not sure if I can do it using `scipy.optimise`. Can I? Or is there some other python module I can use?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to define new functions, say a and b, with fixed values of y and z, such that your new functions are a(x) = f(x, y<sub>0</sub>, z<sub>0</sub>) and b(x) = g(x, y<sub>0</sub>, z<sub>0</sub>) and then minimize these functions.

Comment: I did try something like this. Created h(x1,x2,y,z)=f(x1,y,z)+g(x2,y,z), and try to minimise h assuming x1 and x2 are independent variables. But, I am not sure if this is right way.